# Using sessions in Django

Tags: python, django, session, django-sessions

I'm using sessions in Django to store login user information as well as some other information. I've been reading through the Django session website and still have a few questions.

From the Django website:

> By default, Django stores sessions in
>   your database (using the model
>   `django.contrib.sessions.models.Session`).
>   Though this is convenient, in some
>   setups it’s faster to store session
>   data elsewhere, so Django can be
>   configured to store session data on
>   your filesystem or in your cache.

Also:

> For persistent, cached data, set
>   `SESSION_ENGINE` to
>   `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db`.
>   This uses a write-through cache –
>   every write to the cache will also be
>   written to the database. Session reads
>   only use the database if the data is
>   not already in the cache.

Is there a good rule of thumb for which one to use? `cached_db` seems like it would always be a better choice because best case, the data is in the cache, and worst case it's in the database where it would be anyway.  The one downside is I have to setup memcached.

> By default, `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` is set
>   to `False`, which means session cookies
>   will be stored in users' browsers for
>   as long as `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`. Use
>   this if you don't want people to have
>   to log in every time they open a
>   browser.

Is it possible to have both, the session expire at the browser close AND give an age?

> If value is an integer, the session
>   will expire after that many seconds of
>   inactivity. For example, calling
>   `request.session.set_expiry(300)` would
>   make the session expire in 5 minutes.

What is considered "inactivity"?

> If you're using the database backend, note that session data can
>   accumulate in the `django_session`
>   database table and Django does not
>   provide automatic purging. Therefore,
>   it's your job to purge expired
>   sessions on a regular basis.

So that means, even if the session is expired there are still records in my database.  Where exactly would one put code to "purge the db"?  I feel like you would need a seperate thread to just go through the db every once in awhile (Every hour?) and delete any expired sessions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a good rule of thumb for which one to use?

No.

> Cached_db seems like it would always be a better choice ...

That's fine.

In some cases, there a many Django (and Apache) processes querying a common database.  `mod_wsgi` allows a lot of scalability this way. The cache doesn't help much because the sessions are distributed randomly among the Apache (and Django) processes.

> Is it possible to have both, the session expire at the browser close AND give an age?

Don't see why not.

> What is considered "inactivity"?

I assume you're kidding.  "activity" is -- well -- activity.  You know.  Stuff happening in Django.  A GET or POST request that Django can see.  What else could it be?

> Where exactly would one put code to "purge the db"?

Put it in crontab or something similar.

> I feel like you would need a seperate thread to just go through the db every once in awhile (Every hour?)

Forget threads (please).  It's a separate process.  Once a day is fine. How many sessions do you think you'll have?

Comment: For a big site with lots of users maybe you'd have a lot of sessions?  I don't know what "crontab" is so I'll definitely look into that.  I was also thinking that "activity" could mean updating or accessing the session.

Comment: @JPC: Define "big" and "lots" first.  Then figure out how many sessions.  They're not a big database burden.  "activity" as in "accessing the session" would be exactly the same as any GET/POST request handled by Django -- what else could it mean?